# A script to insert email address into sender_access_regexp (and add a regexp)

Tags: regex, postfix-mta

I, a complete noob even by skiddie standards, am trying to write a script that would do following:

1. ask for an email address (as an input)
2. run sudoedit on /etc/postfix/sender_access_regexp (as current user)
3. check if duplicate lines exist (meaning if such an address is already listed in above mentioned file)
4. insert the provided email address if it is unique
5. add `/^.*` before address
6. append `$/ REJECT` after address
7. write and quit
8. run postmap /etc/postfix/sender_access_regexp (as current user)
9. run postfix reload (as current user)

So far, I've got the easy part done, getting the script to ask for an email address, just so:

`echo -e "\nPlease enter user's email address to add to Sender Access blocklist:"`

`read -p 'Email:' USERMAIL`

I'm not lazy and looking only for a copy/paste solution (but I won't mind one), so if you can point me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have several tasks/steps here... Do you have problems with all of them? Or do you have some specific problem?

Comment: I've finished step 1), now i'd like to get through other steps as well - problem is, no ammount of googling gave me the result I needed. Perhaps I'm not asking the right questions...

But yes, I have problems with all steps from 2) and on

Answer (score 0):

Well, digging a wee bit deeper, I've managed to piece together different bits and pieces to form a functioning script. It is by far not the prettiest beast out there, but considering it was literally my first - I'm happy :) I'll share it here in it's entirety in case someone else needs it as well.

```
#!/bin/bash

## USERMAIL is a mail address to be added to the blocklist
COUNTER=0
while [ $COUNTER -lt 1 ]; do
    clear ## clears the screen
    echo -e "\nPlease enter user's email address to add to Sender Access blocklist (to minimize errors, please copy the email address):"
    echo ""
    read -p 'Email:' USERMAIL ## this is where user provides an email

    if 
            grep $USERMAIL /etc/postfix/sender_access_regexp;
                    then echo -e "\nUser already exists on this list." ## this checks if there is such an address on the list already
            else 
                    echo /^.*$USERMAIL$/ REJECT >> /etc/postfix/sender_access_regexp ## the bits and pieces surrounding $USERMAIL are all part of regex
                    echo -e "\nUser $USERMAIL added to blocklist."
                    echo ""
    fi
    echo""
    read -p "Would you like to add another addres to Sender Access blocklist? (y/n)" -n 1 -r
    echo ""
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
            then let COUNTER=COUNTER+0
            echo ""
    else let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
    echo ""
    fi
done

postmap /etc/postfix/sender_access_regexp
postfix reload

echo ""
read -n 1 -s -r -p "All done, press any key to continue"
echo ""
```

There, that's it. All those  `echo ""`  are there because I didn't know how to add an empty line :shrug:

P.S. you might get  `permission denied`  if the owner of the  `/etc/postifx/sender_access_regexp`  and your script are not the same user.

P.P.S. all suggestions on smoothing this script out are still welcome!